# Central air winterization and insulation

Tags: hvac

Do I need to insulate the skinny copper line on the outside to keep it from freezing and bursting during the cold winter months?  Anything else I need to do winterize the a.c. unit?

Answer (score 1):

No. There's nothing that really needs to be done, as the units are designed to be outside.  The refrigerant in the lines will not freeze, so you don't have to worry about the lines bursting. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-410A) lists the melting point of R-410A at -247°F<sup>†</sup>, so it would have to get fairly cold before you'd have to worry.

Some folks like to cover them, but that's not recommended. Covering the units can give mold and mildew a lovely place to grow, especially in the spring when temperatures begin to rise.

If the unit is in a place where snow thrown by shovels, blowers, or plows will hit it. Then you might want to build something to protect the unit. Just make sure anything you build allows adequate air flow, while also providing protection.

<sup>†</sup> *Melting point is at atmospheric pressure.*

Comment: I think at -247F you have more concerns than "will my air conditioner turn on" unless maybe you're on Mercury.